# FOR loop to calculate difference on dates in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, difference, datediff

I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates in a data frame in days and save it in another column of the same data frame called lag. This is my code but it is not working:

```
Daily_Streamflow$Date
Daily_Streamflow$lag[1] <- 0
j <- 2
for (j in length(Daily_Streamflow$Date)) {
 Daily_Streamflow$lag[j] <-  as.numeric(difftime(Daily_Streamflow$Date[j],Daily_Streamflow$Date[j-1], unit=c("days")))
 j <- j + 1
}
```

This is how my data frame looks:

[image]

When I set the difference for the first day `Daily_Streamflow$lag[1]` equal to 0 all the remaining values are set to 0. If I keep this value empty, all the values of the column are set to `NA`. It seems that the code put the value of the first lag to all the column, omitting the function inside the for, though the j value increases and the loop runs.

Comment: When using the `for (j in 2:length(df$Date))` loop you don't need the `j <- j + 1`. You can also avoid looping altogether for this case with 
`Daily_Streamflow %>%  mutate(lag = replace_na(as.numeric(Date - lag(Date)), 0))`. This assumes your Date column is saved as a date object. If it isn't, first convert it with `as.Date()`. Also the `replace_na()` function requires the library `tidyr`

Comment: How the function mutate knows only with ```Date - lag(Date)``` that you want to calculate the difference between that date and the previous date if you do not specify position?

Comment: Also the ```tydr``` package it is not available for the last version of R 4.0.2

Comment: tidyr, not tydr. Its part of tidyverse. lag will shift the entire column by +1 rows. While lead will shift a column -1 rows. Test `lag(Daily_Streamflow$Date)` in your console to visualise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide data for us, you have to test this by yourself:

```
Daily_Streamflow$Date
Daily_Streamflow$lag[1] <- 0
for (j in 2:length(Daily_Streamflow$Date)) { # add 2: to create a sequence
  Daily_Streamflow$lag[j] <-  as.numeric(difftime(Daily_Streamflow$Date[j],Daily_Streamflow$Date[j-1], units=c("days")), units = "days") # change 'unit' to 'units' and add 'units' attribute to the 'as.numeric' function as well
  j <- j + 1
}
```