# R: Loop through columns in tibble to find differences between each and create new for each difference

Tags: r, loops, na, tibble

I have been working on this for a while now, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm looking for a solution that can: calculate difference between col1 and col2 and create colA based on this; then calculate difference between col2 and col3 and create colB based on this, etc. etc. I have about 70 rows and 42 of these columns so it's not something I want to do by hand (at this point I am almost desperate enough).

To give a note also, some of the cells in the rows are empty (NA). An emergency solution would be to fill these with zeroes, but I'd rather not.

Also, the dataframe I use is a tibble, however, I am not bound to this so much that I can't change it to a real dataframe.

My data looks like this:
[testdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnbrD.png)

As you can see, the columns have annoyingly long names I did not know how to change also :). I use the column numbers usually, which are 77:119. I hope this is complete enough. Sorry for the noob-ness and possibly unclear explanation, this is my first question on here and I'm not that craftsy in R!

Finally, to create the 'user/intermittent_answers/n_length' columns I used the following loop, so I thought it'd be possible to reuse this for the calculations that I need now.

```
#loop through PARTS of testdata to create _length's
for(i in names(testdata[34:76]))
  testdata[[paste(i, 'length', sep="_")]] <- str_length(testdata[[i]])
```

Then I tried something similar which I found here: [FOR loop to calculate difference on dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953445/for-loop-to-calculate-difference-on-dates-in-r)

```
for (j in 2:length(testdata$`user/intermittant_answers/42_length`))
+ testdata$lag[j] <- as.numeric(difftime(testdata$`user/intermittant_answers/42_length`[j], testdata$`user/intermittant_answers/42_length`[j-1], units=c("difference")), units = "days")
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I figured this was because I am not working with anything time related, but I don't know/don't know how to find another 'diff' related function that is not bound to matrixes like the one from matrixStats package.

I hope someone can push me in the right direction!

Thank you!!

EDIT: @Ben, thank you for responding! If I had known this function I would've used it way sooner :'). I tried to keep a representation of NA values inside the df. Also, some people suggested using a double loop, however, I have not managed to figure this out. I hope this helps!

```
> dput(testdata[1:10, 95:105])
structure(list(`user/intermittant_answers/18_length` = c(NA, 
24L, 34L, 33L, NA, NA, 16L, NA, 25L, 28L), `user/intermittant_answers/19_length` = c(NA, 
38L, 68L, 34L, NA, 11L, 20L, 12L, 47L, 52L), `user/intermittant_answers/20_length` = c(NA, 
59L, 81L, 42L, 2L, 33L, 20L, 26L, 96L, 78L), `user/intermittant_answers/21_length` = c(6L, 
90L, 116L, 42L, 14L, 41L, 20L, NA, 127L, 113L), `user/intermittant_answers/22_length` = c(17L, 
115L, 131L, 65L, 20L, 70L, 37L, 11L, 170L, 130L), `user/intermittant_answers/23_length` = c(40L, 
138L, 188L, 65L, 38L, 113L, 22L, 24L, 200L, 136L), `user/intermittant_answers/24_length` = c(66L, 
155L, 210L, 99L, 49L, 133L, 41L, 49L, 242L, 185L), `user/intermittant_answers/25_length` = c(66L, 
158L, 233L, 99L, 65L, 156L, 67L, 70L, 296L, 224L), `user/intermittant_answers/26_length` = c(84L, 
201L, 250L, 113L, 84L, 164L, 67L, 78L, 334L, 224L), `user/intermittant_answers/27_length` = c(89L, 
237L, 285L, 130L, 97L, 167L, 84L, 86L, 412L, 232L), `user/intermittant_answers/28_length` = c(116L, 
284L, 315L, 130L, 97L, 184L, 97L, 108L, 445L, 247L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi @nicoleouise! Welcome to SO! I'd like to help. One thing that would help me, is to have example data to work with. Instead of an image, would you be willing to try something like `dput(testdata[1:10, 1:10])` for first 10 rows and 10 columns? Once you have output for this, edit your question and then copy/paste it in.